# Highcharts.js background pattern

Tags: html, css, highcharts

Hi someone give me to produce an htm; navigation like this
[image]

but i have a hard time to make this in html.
I manage to get very close with highcharts.js 
but i can get the two color background in every slice.

Any ideas?

If you have a better idea how can i transform this in an html navigation
menu i would like to hear it.

Comment: Show us your code so far

Comment: An hacky way of doing this with highcharts would be to place a div under the chart with the image you provided then build a pie on top of it with the same exact size and catch the click on the slices.

Comment: Using Highcharts - you could add partially transparent white ring over a pie chart using renderer or use 2 pie series - inner and outer one. Please post Highcharts code you have so far for demos of solutions.